# ubuntu app wont let me change directory using the cd command

Tags: command-line

I recently installed the Ubuntu app in Windows and when I first installed it it was working fine but it won't let me change directory when I type in cd Desktop, or another cd command. It keeps sayin no such file or directory. Now I'm wondering if it's because I have the Ubuntu app installed but not the actual linux o.s and maybe the shell cannot see the desktop? Could that be it? Please bare with me I'm new to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have the ubuntu app installed"?

Comment: I assume that you're using Ubuntu app on Windows 10, i.e., WSL. In which directory were you when you used `cd Desktop`? Do you want to access Windows' Desktop folder or Ubuntu's?

Comment: yes I have it installed on windows 10 . thats a good question can i access windows desktop since I dont have the linux o.s installed

Comment: I was in the home directory trying to access the deskop

Comment: What I mean is are you trying to `cd` to Ubuntu's Desktop folder or Windows'? What is the output of `pwd` before you run the `cd` command?

Comment: Ubuntu in WSL has no such those directories at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change your directory with cd command, you should enter a path directory after cd:

```
cd your_path_directory
```

Path can be relative or absolute.
In relative path you enter a path from where you are now. For example, if your terminal open in home directory you can easily go to Desktop with this commad:

```
cd Desktop
```

because a Desktop directory is in your home but if you aren't in home you must enter a path apropriate for this situation.
For example if you are in Downloads directory you should run:

```
cd ../Desktop
```

You can also use absolute path like this:

```
cd /home/yourusername/Desktop
```

or replace /home/*yourusername* with ~:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

If you want have a better understanding about it you can read [the linux cammand line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) book. it has a complete explaination for path.

Comment: Thankyou you guys so much for helping me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

WSL shells by default start in a directory that is different from your windows home directory. But WSL shells can see windows directories.

If your username is 'myname', you would `cd /mnt/c/Users/myname/Desktop`

If you just `cd /mnt/c/Users/myname/` you will see your usual windows directories like Documents.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for helping me